# How to convert a unicode string to upper/lower/title case using Python's C API avoiding functions deprecated in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, c, api, unicode

As described in

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#unicode-character-properties,

Py_UNICODE_TOUPPER and friends are deprecated since Python 3.3, when PEP 393 was implemented. However, there does not seem any replacement. In particular, the C API does not seem to allow calls to the underlying C functions of methods such as 'abc'.upper().

Does this mean that the C API, since Python 3.3, no longer supports these basic str conversions? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the methods.  See the [Call Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html).

Example:

**test.c**

```c
#include <Python.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
PyObject* upper(PyObject* arg) {
    return PyObject_CallMethod(arg,"upper",NULL);
}
```

Demo using `ctypes`:

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = PyDLL('./test')
>>> dll.upper.argtypes = py_object,
>>> dll.upper.restype = py_object
>>> dll.upper('hello')
'HELLO'
```